# Is it dead or alive? When?

Tags: riddle

If you break me before my time
I am dead, don't waste your time.
If I don't break when I'm supposed
throw me away, don't be opposed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably

> an **egg**.

If you break me before my time
I am dead, don't waste your time.

> Breaking an egg before it hatches will kill it, it will not hatch.

If I don't break when I'm supposed
throw me away, don't be opposed.

> If it doesn't hatch when it's supposed to (within reason of course) then the egg is dead, it's not going to hatch; get rid of it before it spoils.
>  <sub>From the OP's comment on another answer, the fact that the egg breaks on its own is perhaps an important distinction, even though the wording actually used does not strictly imply this.</sub>

The title:

> Probably questioning if an egg is dead or alive.  It's not "alive" in the usual until the creature within hatches, but neither is it really dead as long as the creature inside is still developing.

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> a [glowstick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_stick)?

If you break me before my time
I am dead, don't waste your time.

> If you snap the inner tube of the glowstick (the part that keeps the chemicals separated until you want the stick to produce light) before you're ready, there's no way to make it stop glowing, so you shouldn't waste your time trying.

If I don't break when I'm supposed
throw me away, don't be opposed.

> Some glowsticks simply don't snap, and don't produce light - because they're faulty, or because they've already been used - in which case one shouldn't hesitate to throw them away, because there's nothing that can be done for them.

Comment: It's not a bad analogy, but pay attention to the person of the action "break". First it's "if you break me", then it's "if I don't break"...

Answer (score 3):

You are

> a [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(electrical)).

If you break me before my time
I am dead, don't waste your time.

> If you blow a fuse before it's inserted into the circuit, don't bother repairing it (although sometimes I did, in my younger days). Just take a replacement.

If I don't break when I'm supposed
throw me away, don't be opposed.

> A fuse that does not blow up when reaching the tripping current is even worse, it is outright dangerous and you should throw it away (and not only because the electric equipment it was supposed to protect is not there anymore)

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Helmet

If you break me before my time
I am dead, don't waste your time.

> If you drop/break a helmet, it is not safe to use!

If I don't break when I'm supposed
throw me away, don't be opposed.

> Same as above, if the helmet doesn't break in a crash (or doesn't break your head) throw it out!

Comment: why would u throw the helmet if it doesn't break in a crash?

Comment: You are supposed to dispose of any helmet that was in an accident, whether or not it breaks since the integrity is probably weakened

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> heart?  If you stop a heart it will kill them. If their heart doesn't break when it should, then they are not into you.